# connecting to SAP HANA : ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python-3.x, hana

I am trying to connect SAP HANA DB through Python using Putty(Ubuntu) with the below script but receiving Connection Refused error.

> Error: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Note: The SAP HANA which I am trying to connect is hosted on AWS server.

```
import pyhdb
class hana(object):
     def opencon(self):
     conn= pyhdb.connect(host='10.1.3.66',
                         port=XXXXX,
                         user='XXXXX',
                         password='XXXXX')
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   print(conn.isconnected())
HanaDB = hana()
HanaDB.opencon()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to connect to your instance with other HANA clients, like SAP HANA Studio or `hdbsql`?

Right now, it just looks like the connection gets refused on the TCP/IP level, maybe due to some firewall setting!?